# Angular: custom input with ControlValueAccessor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, angular-reactive-forms

I'm not sure how can I use a custom component if it's wrapper under another component.

Like:

```
ComponentA_withForm
|
--ComponentA1_withWrapperOfCustomInput
  |
  --ComponentA11_withCustomInput
```

if I have a structure like this:

```
ComponentA_withForm
|
--ComponentA11_withCustomInput
```

Everything's fine

But for my case (tons of async data) I need a wrapper... Is it possible somehow to do this?

Here is my fiddle code:

ComponentA:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<form [formGroup]="form"><custom-input-wrapper formControlName="someInput"></custom-input-wrapper></form> <p>value is: {{formVal | json}}</p>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  form = this.fb.group({
    someInput: [],
  });

  get formVal() {
    return this.form.getRawValue();
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
}
```

ComponentA1:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input-wrapper',
  template: '<custom-input></custom-input>',
})
export class CustomInputWrapperComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

ComponentA11:

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `Hey there! <button (click)="inc()">Value: {{ value }}</button>`,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
    multi: true,
  }],
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  private value = 0;

  writeValue(value: number): void {
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChangeFn = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  }

  inc() {
    this.value = this.value + 1;
    this.onChangeFn(this.value);
  }

  onChangeFn = (_: any) => { };
}
```

And here I have a working sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmrj3a

so: basically removing & refactoring code not to use `CustomInputWrapperComponent` makes my code working. But I need this wrapper and I'm not sure how to pass `formControlName` then.

I don't want a dirty solution with passing parent formGroup :)

Comment: Why not implement `ControlValueAccessor` in your `CustomInputWrapperComponent` as well ?

Comment: @abd995I think it's dirty way as well :)

Comment: I think that's most cleanest solution you could possibly have. Passing in the form control or form group is I guess the dirty solution.

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't want a dirty solution ;) , you could just implement `ControlValueAccessor` in the `CustomInputWrapperComponent` also. That way any change in the parent will be reflected in the child, any change in the child will be reflected in the parent as well with just few lines of code.

**Wrapper Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input-wrapper',
  template: '<custom-input [formControl]="value"></custom-input>',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputWrapperComponent),
    multi: true,
  }]
})
export class CustomInputWrapperComponent implements AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor  {
  public value = new FormControl();

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.value.valueChanges.subscribe((x) => {
      this.onChangeFn(x);
    });
  }

  writeValue(value: number): void {
    this.value.setValue(value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChangeFn = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  }

 onChangeFn = (_: any) => { };
}
```

**Parent Template**

```
<form [formGroup]="form"><custom-input-wrapper formControlName="someInput"></custom-input-wrapper></form> <p>value is: {{formVal | json}}</p>
```

I have made a stackbitz demo here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csaxcz

Comment: If possible could you add the relevant parts of your code to your answer? Link-only answers become irrelevant if the link no longer works, in case of stackblitz demos its also a job for the viewer to find the relevant parts. I would strongly recommend to add comments to the code in case you write them for someone else (like someone asking here on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @SaschaM78 I have added the some parts of the code to the answer. Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot for adding the relevant code parts, this makes the answer way more comprehensible.

Comment: @abd995 thanks for this solution, it worked great. Only thing I modified, was instead of using `valueChanges` to trigger the onchange fn for the wrapper component, I grabbed the inner component using `ViewChild` and then used it to trigger the onchange like: `this.innerComponent.registerOnTouched(this.onTouched);` since I didn't want `writeValue` to trigger the onchange.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use `formControlName` on `custom-input-wrapper` because it doesn't implement `ControlValueAccessor`. implementing `ControlValueAccessor` on `custom-input-wrapper` might be a solution but it seems to be overkill. Instead pass the control from formGroup to `custom-input-wrapper` as an `@Input()` and pass the inputed formControl to `custom-input`

app.component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<form [formGroup]="form"><custom-input-wrapper [formCtrl]="form.get('someInput')"></custom-input-wrapper></form> <p>value is: {{formVal | json}}</p>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  form = this.fb.group({
    someInput: [],
  });

  get formVal() {
    return this.form.getRawValue();
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
}
```

custom-input-wrapper.component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input-wrapper',
  template: '<custom-input [formControl]="formCtrl"></custom-input>',
})
export class CustomInputWrapperComponent {
  @Input() formCtrl: AbstractControl;
  constructor() { }
}
```

here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3lrfqv

Comment: As the OP had already mentioned.  `I don't want a dirty solution with passing parent formGroup`. Passing formGroup as input might not be the solution he might be looking for.

Comment: Angular docs state that "ControlValueAccessor defines an interface that acts as a bridge between the Angular forms API and a native element in the DOM". imho, implementing `ControlValueAccessor` in `CustomInputWrapperComponent ` is a dirty solution because there is no native element in `CustomInputWrapperComponent ` that needs to be bridged with Angular Forms API.